# Find the minima of $I(a, b) = \int_0^1 (ax + b-x^2)^2 dx$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives

$I(a, b) = \int_0^1 (ax + b-x^2)^2 dx$

How to find the minima of $I(a,b)$?

My idea is like this,

$ I(a,b) = \frac13(ax + b -x^2)^3 \cdot (\frac12 ax^2 + bx - \frac13 x^3) |_0^1$

This is the first step, then next step might be like doing this $ \partial I \over \partial a$ and $ \partial I \over \partial b$.

But I am not sure if this is the right path to continue.

Comment: Your approach will work, except that you didn't do the integration correctly (the chain rule doesn't work like that). Instead you will be forced to expand. There is another approach based on orthogonal polynomials, but it is about the same for this relatively small example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Surely you can proceed as that, but we can differentiate under the integral sign ($[0,1]$ is compact and the integrand is continuously differentiable, say), so:

\begin{align}\frac{\partial I}{\partial a}(a,b) &= \frac{\partial}{\partial a}\int_0^1(ax+b-x^2)^2\,dx = \int_0^1 2x(ax+b-x^2)\, dx \\ &= \int_0^1 2ax^2 + 2bx - 2x^3\, dx = \frac{2a}{3}+b - \frac{1}{2}\end{align} and

\begin{align} \frac{\partial I}{\partial b}(a,b)  &= \frac{\partial}{\partial b}\int_0^1 (ax+b-x^2)^2\, dx = \int_0^1 2(ax+b-x²)\, dx \\ &= a+2b - \frac{2}{3}\end{align}

Well, we have that: $$ \begin{cases} \frac{2a}{3}+b - \frac{1}{2} = 0 \\  a+2b - \frac{2}{3}=0\end{cases} \iff \begin{cases}  4a+6b = 3 \\  3a+6b = 2,\end{cases} $$which has solutions $a = 1$ and $b = -1/6$. So $(1, -1/6)$ is the only critical point of $I$. Can you check that it is a minimum now?

Comment: Yes, I can as I understand your solution completely now. Your approach is better and your idea is smart.